# Get rid of Messages' notifications when application is connected to a PC

Tags: notifications, sms, notification-bar, motorola, motorola-moto-z2-play

I am using and very enjoining the fact I can connect my base Android Messages application to its [web counterpart on my PC](https://messages.android.com/) and get much more flexibility in writing and managing all my SMSes.

But, I am pretty much irritated that it displays so many notifications about the fact that it is being connected to this or that PC:

[image]

I think that I see it dozen of times:

- daily, each time I start a PC,
- each time I restart my browser and
- even each time my Messages application / mobile phone looses and regains connection to the Internet and thus Messages application and its browser counterpart reconnects each other.

Is there any way to disable this pseudo-security messages?

I can't find corresponding configuration option in either Messages application on my Android phone or in its web counter part. And I am afraid to force-block notifications from this mobile application in my Android settings becuase I think that I will loose all the notifications from it, i.e. not just those about being connected, but also notifications about received SMS message.

The same goes for notification about using mobile plan, in web counterpart:

[image]

Is there any way of getting rid of it permanently or do I have to close this nag everyday, every time I restart my browser?

Comment: Interesting, I've never had such a nagging problem with it like you describe. I reconnected mine to see just what it does for me, and my phone doesn't even tell me I'm connected to the web version.

Answer (score 1):

For disabling first notifications (i.e. the one that appears on the phone when it is connected to PC) one must:

- tap such notification (or select *Messages for web* from three-dot menu in Messages application),
- tap three-dots menu and select *Notifications* and
- uncheck *Show presistent notification* option.

[image]

As for disabling second notifications (i.e. the one appears in PC / Chrome / web browser version of Messages for web, about phone using mobile data) this is most likely solved in the Google-way.

Thus there is no way to disable this because Google thinks that you must see this and doesn't actually care what you really need or want, sorry.